# # Aidl not found, please install it

Tags: ubuntu, aidl, buildozer

I am trying to run `buildozer`. While running it gave the following error:

```
Aidl not found, please install it.
```

So I tried to install aidl as described [here](http://thelinuxfaq.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-17-04-zesty-zapus/aidl)
But it gave me the following error

> E: Unable to locate package aidl

I have updated the package index by `sudo apt-get update`,but stil it is not working. How can I install `aidl`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install `build-tools` from `android sdk manager`. You can find more info [Installing the Android SDK and Tools](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E60665_01/salescs_gs/OSDMA/bizcard-uc-setup002.htm#OSDMA6713) in the **Task 2   Install Additional Android Packages**

Comment: I thought all dependencies are installed automatically when it's missing when you run `buildozer android debug deploy run`

Comment: Sadly, the link is dead.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I have found the solution. To install `aidl`, you need `libstdc++-6`. Previously I had a lower version of `libstdc++`, which causes problems while installing `aidl`.

To update to `libstdc++-6`, try

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6
```

After this, you will have `libstdc++6` installed.now you can simply install the `aidl` by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install aidl
```

Answer (score 2):

For me it worked:

**buildozer.spec**

```
android.accept_sdk_license = True
android.skip_update = False
```

Comment: This seems to do the trick. I had to delete `~/.buildozer` and `.buildozer` folders before trying again.

Answer (score 0):

after some lost brain cells i finally found the solution for it

here is what i did

```
$ sudo apt-get install aidl 
... 
$ which aidl /usr/bin/aidl
$ cp /usr/bin/aidl ~/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/build-tools/31.0.0/
$ chmod 777 ~/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/build-tools/31.0.0/aidl
```

and yeah that just solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

First head to the `cmdline-tools` folder which `sdkmanager` is in it then run

`./sdkmanager "build-tools;<VERSION>"`

Once its finished; It should be in parent directory so you should change it with

`cp -r build-tools cmdline-tools/cmdline-tools/`

So buildozer can find it correctly. Now it should be like

```
.
├── android-ndk-r25c
│   ├── bla bla bla
│   └── bla bla bla
├── cmdline-tools
│   ├── 9.0
│   ├── build-tools
│   ├── licenses
│   ├── platform-tools
│   └── tools
```