# Python OSError with aidl while executing [buildozer]

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, buildozer, aidl

When i do 'buildozer -v android debug' on my raspberry, i get an error :

```
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: '/home/x/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/build-tools/34.0.0-rc3/aidl'
```

does the error came from the aidl or me ?
What can i do ?

i run `buildozer -v android debug` on my raspberry-pi and it didn't work (i got an error, [Errno 8])

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem after running the same command. I was also using a Raspberry Pi.

Reinstalling Aidl and copying over the new Aidl files (https://stackoverflow.com/a/68654306) helped solve the problem for me. Hope this helps!